# webpack + babel transpilation for IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs, transpiler

I have client side js assets that are written in ES6 modules. I am using Webpack and Babel to transpile for other browsers but I cannot get it to cater to IE10. Even if I specify IE10 explicitly in the configs it does not fix any unsupported keywords, functions, or properties. What am I doing wrong? Is IE10 still currently supported by Webpack + Babel?

Examples of code that I have authored that is not being transpiled:

- String#startsWith
- NodeList#forEach

### tranpilation issues

I have a fair amount of tranpilation runtime issues too.

I am importing and using the `js-cookie` npm module like this:

```js
import * as jsCookies from '../../../node_modules/js-cookie/src/js.cookie';
...
...
...
const cookieValue = jsCookies.getJSON(cookieName) || {};
```

at run time I am getting this error from the `bundle`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _node_modules_js_cookie_src_js_cookie__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.getJSON is not a function
    at Object.get (bundle.js:5208)
```

console logging the value of the imported `jsCookies` variable shows this:

```js
Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true
__proto__: Object
```

---

I am importing the `time-convert` npm module like this:

```js
import * as timeConvert from '../../../node_modules/time-convert';
```

and it produces this error at run time:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: milliseconds is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (bundle.js:5259)
```

I believe it is to do with the "double" assignment being done here: https://github.com/thk2b/time-convert/blob/master/index.js#L63. But I don't understand as the browser I am testing this on (Chrome latest) supports this! But if this was transpiled correctly in the first place, hopefully this issue would disappear.

---

not to mention that it does not change `const`, and `let` keywords to `var`s.

---

```
bundle.js:558 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'axios' of undefined at bundle.js:558
```

My bundle looks like this:

```js
555 | ...
556 | /* axios v0.19.2 | (c) 2020 by Matt Zabriskie */
557 | !function (e, t) {
558 |     "object" == (typeof exports === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _babel_runtime_helpers_typeof__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_29___default()(exports)) && "object" == ( false ? undefined : _babel_runtime_helpers_typeof__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_29___default()(module)) ? module.exports = t() : "function" == typeof define && __webpack_require__(/*! !webpack amd options */ "./node_modules/webpack/buildin/amd-options.js") ? define([], t) : "object" == (typeof exports === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _babel_runtime_helpers_typeof__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_29___default()(exports)) ? exports.axios = t() : e.axios = t();
559 |   }(undefined, function () {
560 |     return function (e) {
561 |       function t(r) {
562 |         if (n[r]) return n[r].exports;
563 | ...
```

Looking here: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/dist/axios.js#L11, this issue is that Webpack replaces `this` with `undefined` and then Axios breaks. Given that Axios is already precompiled is there another way I can include it in the bundle without having to do any.

the Webpack `globalObject` property didn't help here.

---

these warnings are logged on the server in the above situation also:

```
| WARNING in ./src/modules/cookie-preference/index.js 28:28-45
| "export 'getJSON' (imported as 'jsCookies') was not found in '../../../node_modules/js-cookie/src/js.cookie'
|  @ ./src/js/scripts.js
|  @ multi ./components/cica/modal/modal.js ./node_modules/axios ./src/js/scripts.js
|
| WARNING in ./src/modules/modal-timeout/index.js 19:41-54
| "export 'm' (imported as 'timeConvert') was not found in '../../../node_modules/time-convert'
|  @ ./src/js/scripts.js
|  @ multi ./components/cica/modal/modal.js ./node_modules/axios ./src/js/scripts.js
```

So because of all these issues, I have only been able to get it working by configuring it to exclude the contents of the node_modules directory and any imports from that directory are just "copied" over in to the `bundle.js` file. Making it useless for older browsers.

### configs

#### package.json:

```
{
    "browserslist": [
        "defaults",
        "last 2 versions",
        "ie >= 9",
        "Safari >= 12",
        "ios_saf >= 10",
        "iOS >= 10"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.5",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "core-js": "^3.5.0",
        "webpack": "^4.41.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

#### webpack.config.js:

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'bundle.js': [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/cica/modal/modal.js'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/scripts.js')
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name]',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/js')
    },
    devtool: 'none',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/js-cookie/'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/axios/'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/time-convert/')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

#### babel.config.js

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = api => {
    api.cache(false);
    const presets = [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                corejs: {
                    version: 3
                },
                useBuiltIns: 'usage'
            }
        ]
    ];
    const plugins = [
        ['@babel/transform-runtime']
    ];
    return {
        presets,
        plugins
    };
};
```

#### runnning `npx browserlist`

```
and_chr 84
and_ff 68
and_qq 10.4
and_uc 12.12
android 81
baidu 7.12
bb 10
bb 7
chrome 84
chrome 83
chrome 81
chrome 80
edge 84
edge 83
edge 18
firefox 78
firefox 77
firefox 76
firefox 68
ie 11
ie 10
ie 9
ie_mob 11
ie_mob 10
ios_saf 13.4-13.5
ios_saf 13.3
ios_saf 13.2
ios_saf 13.0-13.1
ios_saf 12.2-12.4
ios_saf 12.0-12.1
ios_saf 11.3-11.4
ios_saf 11.0-11.2
ios_saf 10.3
ios_saf 10.0-10.2
kaios 2.5
node 14.5.0
node 12.18.0
node 10.21.0
op_mini all
op_mob 46
op_mob 12.1
opera 69
opera 68
safari 13.1
safari 13
safari 12.1
safari 12
samsung 12.0
samsung 11.1-11.2
```

Comment: I think Babel generally advises excluding `node_modules` from transpilation -- Webpack should deal with concatenating the files together. I have had to manually import polyfills for things like `String#startsWith` in the past, for reasons that remain unclear, but that might help?

Comment: also is there a specific reason you're using `import * as timeConvert from '../../../node_modules/time-convert';` as opposed to `import * as timeConvert from 'time-convert';`?